# I know it is not null, but Dart doesn't know that. How do I tell it?

Tags: dart

The code Dart is complaining about:

```dart
Map<String,int> get_frequency(String text) { 
  Map<String,int> retval = {};
  for (int i = 0; i<text.length; ++i) { 
    retval[text[i]] = retval[text[i]] ?? 0;
    retval[text[i]]++; //<---- this is where dart is complaining.*
  }
  return retval;
}

void main() {
  const paragraphOfText = 'Once upon a time there was a Dart programmer who '
      'had a challenging challenge to solve. Though the challenge was great, '
      'a solution did come. The end.';
  var data = get_frequency(paragraphOfText);
  print(data);
}
```

Obviously the line marked with (*) can not be null, so how do I tell that to Dart? I tried  the null assertion operator (!), but that didn't work.

Null Safety is enabled.

Error message:

```
challenge2.dart:5:20: Error: Operator '+' cannot be called on 'int?' because it is potentially null.
    retval[text[i]]++;
                   ^
challenge2.dart:5:20: Error: A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
    retval[text[i]]++;
                   ^
```

Comment: If Dart is "complaining" ... THEN PLEASE COPY/PASTE THE EXACT ERROR MESSAGE INTO YOUR QUESTION!  Q: Is [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to change the line

```dart
    retval[text[i]]++; //<---- this is where dart is complaining.*
```

into

```dart
    retval[text[i]] = retval[text[i]]! + 1;
```

Just figured it out.

Comment: Yes, in general, that is what you must do.  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1113.  In your case, you also could have combined it with the previous line: `retval[text[i]] = (retval[text[i]] ?? 0) + 1;`